# Prevent the cookie "x-bni-ci" from being removed in varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

We are trying to prevent the cookie `x-bni-ci` from being stripped out by varnish. We have a line that removes unrecognized cookies in our vcl file:

```
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
```

The cookie needs to be allowed for all URLs.

We are using Varnish 4

Answer (score 1):

Can you install the [VMOD cookie](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/docs/cookie.rst)?

If so, you could do the following...

```
import cookie;

    sub vcl_recv {
            cookie.parse(req.http.Cookie);
            cookie.filter_except("x-bni-ci");
    }
```